# New-AzVM : Parameter 'osProfile' is not allowed

Tags: azure, powershell, credentials

I'm using powershell to create a disk from a snapshot (windows 10), then create a VM, attaching that OS disk to it. On creating the VM, I get that the parameter osProfile is not allowed. Thanks for any help. This all started recently once microsoft apparently rolled out some changes, and I cant find anything on their website to help. And actually I found one other website that basically said microsoft wont fix it, so just deal with it.

```
$snapshot = Get-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName RG -SnapshotName snap-mysnapshot
$diskConfig = New-AzDiskConfig -AccountType $storageType -Location $location -CreateOption Copy -SourceResourceId $snapshot.Id -OsType Windows
New-AzDisk -Disk $diskConfig -ResourceGroupName RG -DiskName 123456789 -Verbose
$osDisk = Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName RG -DiskName 123456789

$azureLocation              = "EastUS"
$azureVmOsDiskName          = "123456789"
$azureVmSize                = "Standard_F4s_v2"
$azureNicName               = "123456789"
$azurePublicIpName          = "123456789"
$azureVnetName              = "25"
$azureVnetSubnetName        = "111"

$azureVnetSubnet = (Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $azureVnetName -ResourceGroupName RG).Subnets | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $azureVnetSubnetName}

$azureNIC = New-AzNetworkInterface -Name 123456789 -ResourceGroupName RG -Location $azureLocation -SubnetId $azureVnetSubnet.Id -Force

$ComputerName = "ComputerName"
$VMLocalAdminUser = "admin"
$VMLocalAdminSecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($VMLocalAdminUser,     $VMLocalAdminSecurePassword);
  
$VirtualMachine = New-AzVMConfig -VMName 123456789 -VMSize $azureVmSize
$VirtualMachine = Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -VM $VirtualMachine -Id $azureNIC.Id -DeleteOption Delete
$VirtualMachine = Set-AzVMOSDisk -VM $VirtualMachine -ManagedDiskId $osDisk.Id -StorageAccountType Premium_LRS -Name 123456789 -CreateOption Attach -Windows -DeleteOption Delete -Verbose
$VirtualMachine = Set-AzVMOperatingSystem -VM $VirtualMachine -Credential $Credential -ComputerName $ComputerName -Windows -Verbos -ProvisionVMAgent -EnableAutoUpdate

New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName RG -Location $azureLocation -VM $VirtualMachine -Verbose
```

Use -ComputerName in New-AzVM now that it's required, which also seems to require credentials. Once adding these new required fields, our scripts fail

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a disk from a snapshot, then create a **VM**, attaching that **OS disk** to it. On creating the VM, I'm also getting the same error

[image]

Here is the updated PowerShell script to create a disk from a snapshot, then create a **VM**, attaching that OS disk

```
   $storageType = "Premium_LRS"
$location = "East US"
$azureVnetName = "Demosubnet"
$azureVnetSubnetName = "samplesubnet"

$diskConfig = New-AzDiskConfig -Location $location -CreateOption Copy -SourceResourceId $snapshot.Id -OsType Windows

# Step 1: Create OS Disk from Snapshot

$snapshot = Get-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName "Sri" -SnapshotName "samplesanp"

$diskConfig = New-AzDiskConfig -Location $location -CreateOption Copy -SourceResourceId $snapshot.Id -OsType Windows

#$diskConfig = New-AzDiskConfig -AccountType $storageType -Location $location -CreateOption Copy -SourceResourceId $snapshot.Id -OsType Windows

New-AzDisk -Disk $diskConfig -ResourceGroupName "Sri" -DiskName "venkat" -Verbose

$osDisk = Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName "Sri" -DiskName "venkat" 

# Step 2: Create Network Interface and Virtual Network

$azureVnetSubnet = (Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $azureVnetName -ResourceGroupName Sri).Subnets | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $azureVnetSubnetName}

$azureNIC = New-AzNetworkInterface -Name "venkat1" -ResourceGroupName "Sri" -Location $location -SubnetId $azureVnetSubnet.Id -Force

# Step 3: Set VM Credentials
$VMLocalAdminUser = "Venkat"
$VMLocalAdminSecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "Welcome@123$" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($VMLocalAdminUser, $VMLocalAdminSecurePassword)
$VMName ="venkat"   # Updated the VM name to match the disk name
$azureVmOsDiskName = "venkat"
$azureVmSize = "Standard_F4s_v2"

$VirtualMachine = New-AzVMConfig -VMName $VMName -VMSize $azureVmSize -SecurityType TrustedLaunch
$VirtualMachine = Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -VM $VirtualMachine -Id $azureNIC.Id

$VirtualMachine = Set-AzVMOSDisk -VM $VirtualMachine -ManagedDiskId $osDisk.Id -StorageAccountType "Premium_LRS" -Name $VMName -CreateOption Attach -Windows -DeleteOption Delete -Verbose
New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "Sri" -Location "EastUS" -VM $VirtualMachine -Verbose
```

**Output:**

Once ran the above code `VM` is created successfully.

[image]

Reference:  [Creating a new VM with an existing subnet in another resource group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/new-azvm?view=azps-10.1.0#example-5-creating-a-new-vm-with-an-existing-subnet-in-another-resource-group)

Comment: I get the message that soon "New-AzVM" cmdlet will deploy with the Trusted Launch configuration by default. So I try to pass the security type as Standard, but apparently that doesnt work. It's as if TrustedLaunch is the only option that msoft will accept via powershell.